# How to fix "identifier of an instance of X was altered from 2 to null" in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

I have two domain classes in grails. One is called Book and the other is called Author.
My Book class looks like this,

```
class Book {
   String name

   static constraints = {
      name nullable:false
   }
}
```

And My Author class:

```
class Author {
   String name
   Book book1
   Book book2
   Book book3

   static constraints = {
      name nullable:false
      book1 nullable:false
      book2 nullable:true
      book3 nullable:true
   }
}
```

Ff I create an author with two books and then edit it to one book I got the following error:

```
identifier of an instance of com.apps.Book was altered from 2 to null
```

How to fix it? I am using grails 2.1.1 and sql server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

try set to null book2 and book3 properties before the line `authorInstance.properties = params` in the update method like this:

```
book2 = null
book3 = null

authorInstance.properties = params
```

Answer (score 0):

try using 'hasOne' in Author class:

```
class Author {
   String name
   Book book1, book2, book3
   static hasOne = [ book1:Book, book2:Book, book3:Book ]
}
```

Comment: Will this effect the database mapping ?

Comment: yepp, into the author table 3 columns will be added: book1_id to book3_id

Comment: Cannot refer Book here being non static. hasOne is static.

Comment: you can refer those fields in run-time. You can also define the `book*` fields as usual properties to be able to refer them in compile time. See the update